# How do I sign users in/out of my app with firestore? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've set up cloud firestore as my backend, including setting up the admin SDK but I am unsure how to authenticate users into my app (using email and password). I can't find anywhere in the documentation where it says how to do this (there's a lot on using `pyrebase` and the realtime database). I assume it's going to be something like `firestore.Client().auth(email, password)`.

I've enabled the email/password login option on the firebase console.

```
from google.cloud import firestore
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "PATH to credentials"

db = firestore.Client()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

If you're making a web app, [consider using the Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start). It comes with pre-built auth flows.